# Date type in SQLite

Tags: java, excel, sqlite, date, format

I have an **excel file** in which I have many columns of **dates** which format is **yyyy-mm-dd** when I upload excel file in **SQLite** using java program. All data upload in their respective columns but **date format** automatically change into **dd-mmm-yyyy**.

I am trying to search data between dates but when date format change I can't search properly because SQLite doesn't support **dd-mmm-yyyy** search

Now, what I can do?
Thanks...

Reading data Row vise

```
public static Vector read(String fileName)    {
    Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
    try{
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        //POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            //Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
            List list = new ArrayList();
            while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                list.add(myCell);
            }
            cellVectorHolder.addElement(list);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
    return cellVectorHolder;
```

Data inserted into a database

```
private static void saveToDatabase(Vector dataHolder) {
    String ClientAdd="";
    String Page="";
    String AccessDate="";
    String Dates="";
    String Bytes="";
    System.out.println(dataHolder);

    for(Iterator iterator = dataHolder.iterator();iterator.hasNext();) {
        List list = (List) iterator.next();
        ClientAdd = list.get(0).toString();
        Page = list.get(1).toString();
        AccessDate = list.get(2).toString();
        Dates = list.get(3).toString();

        try {
           // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
           // Connection con = 
             DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", 
             "root", "welcome");

           Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ourimport.db");

           System.out.println("connection made...");
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO our(Name,Class,Rollon,Date) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
            stmt.setString(1, ClientAdd);
            stmt.setString(2, Page);
            stmt.setString(3, AccessDate);
            stmt.setString(4, Dates);
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Data is inserted");
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem in a C# program recently. In SQLite the column was typed as TEXT. Formatting the date explicitly and storing as string solved the issue. To give you a more concrete advice, we would need to see the relevant java code snippets.

Comment: I has been used the TEXT in sqite for date but issue is same. And in java i convert date into string then store in sqlite.

Comment: You convert with `list.get(3).toString();`. Use an explicit format. See [Parsing and Formatting Dates in Java](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/parsing-formatting-dates.html).

Comment: i didn't have any idea of explicit format and how i implement Parsing in list element